# Getting Corrupt data after reading from Redis

Tags: string, go, redis

After doing HGEt in redis for the key I am getting this

```
127.0.0.1:6379> HGET userKey emp
"\b\x0e\x82\x01\b\x01\x10\x9c\x04\x18@ \xb2\x02(\x81\\xb8\x83\xa8\n\x12%s1.abc.com;25082448;1\x1a\x0c\b\x01\x10\xafQ\x18\x01 \x81\x80\x80\b \x01:\x00@\x01J\x06\b\x02\x12\x02s2R\x1b\b\x17\x12\x1abc.comX\x01b\a\b\xafQ\x10\x01\x18\x01\x88\x01\x01\x92\x01\xb5\x02\b\xaf\x02\x12\xaf\x02<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?> <Sd> <Pd> <Pd>sip:abc@pcap.pqr004.abc602.hello.org</Pd> <Pd>tel:+2098765432</Pd> <Ex><Ide>8</Id></Ex> </Pd> </Sd>\xa2\x01\x00"
```

But when I tried to read the same in my go code then print the contents I am getting completely different thing

```
fmt.Println(userDataRedis.HGet(context.Background(),key,Field))
```

I am getting some junk content:

```
 ²08Ӹ%s
```

English Text is coming correctly but the characters which are in beginning are not coming correctly ?
Can anybody knows how to correct this?

Comment: And what is `userDataRedis.HGet()`? And what are the values of `key` and `Field`? Your data in Redis doesn't seem like printable characters, your terminal may trim the printed result.

Comment: userDataRedis gives me the redis instance and I am reading the content of the Key via HGET, here key is userKey and Field is emp

Comment: But what does `Hget()` return? `*redis.StringCmd`? Then you should call `StringCmd.Val()` or `StringCmd.Result()` and print that (and also check the error).

Comment: Hget returns the String, but as the string contains some escape characters the contents are manipulated

Comment: I dont want the string to get interpreted

Comment: `redis.Client.HGet()` returns `*redis.StringCmd`. If your `userDataRedis` returns `string`, there's obviously some logic hidden in it which we don't see. Show it.

Comment: // HGet returns string value of redis HGET command's response
func (rh *RedisConn) HGet(ctx context.Context, key, field string) string {
 res := rh.Conn.HGet(ctx, key, field)
 return res.Val()
}

Comment: So you _are_ calling `Val()`. Please also check the error: `res.Err()` or `res.Result()`.